# Валидация формы и отправка Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, валидация

Есть профиль пользователя с разными функциональными вкладками(личная информация, контакты, работа и тд).
В каждой вкладке поля редактирования информации.
Решил данные отправлять на сервер через Ajax. Что можете посоветовать, может есть готовые валидаторы?
Нужно сделать, как это реализовано в VK. Там по клику на button вызывается прототип-метод js в котором происходит валидация полей форм и вызов ajax.

Дело даже не в валидации, а в том, как собрать все поля (имена формы) и отправить на сервер

Comment: Попробуйте, например, так - http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/ . Если делать своё - собрать все поля можно по наличию общего признака, например класса элемента. 
Валидация формы html5 не подходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У jQuery есть [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).
У HTML5 есть [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData) (уже поддерживается практически всем, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)).